# I want to find the first date for each time a subcat changes or back again, a particular sub cat might be reported more than once

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

Working on an oracle DB.  I have the following data

| Customer | Category | Subcategory | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Feed | Pellets | 05-OCT-23 |
| 1 | Feed | Hay | 18-Sep-23 |
| 1 | Feed | Pellets | 06-Aug-23 |
| 1 | Feed | Pellets | 04-Jul-23 |
| 1 | Feed | Pellets | 21-Jun_23 |
| 1 | Accessories | Lead | 15-May-23 |
| 1 | Accessories | Lead | 01-Mar_23 |

And for each customer and category, I want the first date of each time they return to a subcategory.  e.g. pellets were first purchased on 21/Jun and then a couple of more times after that, then they switched to hay - so we'll report that line, then back to pellets, so want that line again. So a query that extracts

| Customer | Category | Subcategory | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Feed | Pellets | 05-OCT-23 |
| 1 | Feed | Hay | 18-Sep-23 |
| 1 | Feed | Pellets | 21-Jun_23 |
| 1 | Accessories | Lead | 01-Mar_23 |

from the above data

Min with group by doesn't work because it will only give me the first instance of the subcategory, I want the first date each time they return back to the subcatgory.

Looking at other questions on here, I though partition might help, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work right. Maybe rank belongs in there somewhere?

I feel like this is really easy and obvious for someone who knows what they are doing, but clearly that's not me since I'm only a few steps past select * from......

Thankyou in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `gaps and islands` problem, you could use the difference between two row_numbers to give a unique id to each successive group of rows :

```
with cte as (
  select Customer,
       Category,
       Subcategory,
       purchase_date,
       row_number() over (partition by Customer, Category order by purchase_date) -
       row_number() over (partition by Customer, Category, Subcategory order by purchase_date) as grp
  from mytable
)
select CUSTOMER, CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, min(PURCHASE_DATE) as PURCHASE_DATE
from cte
group by CUSTOMER, CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, grp
order by CUSTOMER, CATEGORY desc, PURCHASE_DATE desc
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lIgmZ5If)